# WebView2 are not support windows store?

Tags: c#, uwp, webview2

I'm trying to publish my uwp (universal windows platform) webview2 application on Microsoft Store, but i got this error

" Supported APIs
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
API GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID in shell32.dll is not supported for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
API GetFileVersionInfoSizeW in version.dll is not supported for this application type. Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll calls this API.
API GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID in shell32.dll is not supported for this application type. WebView2Loader.dll calls this API.
API GetFileVersionInfoSizeW in version.dll is not supported for this application type. WebView2Loader.dll calls this API."

how can i fix that?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to publish a Release build?

Comment: So far as I know, the answer should be yes. https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/883

Comment: yes its a release build?

Comment: hello jerry , i dont know what is the problem

Comment: i want release it on microsoft store , i should use Appx format, https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/SampleApps/WV2DeploymentVSInstallerSample

Comment: What's WinUI version you used?